# $.ajax call not working and not display error message

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need your help on my simple script. I want when user click on image (with id="menu_en") to execute external script in php page (in my case english.php), but ajax call is not working. Even using "error:" statement "alert(xhr.status);" does not help me as alert is showing just "0" and hide in second... Where I'm wrong?
Here is my code placed into the body of the page:

```
 <script src='jquery-1.11.3.min.js'></script>       
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){                       
            $('#menu_en').on('click',function(){                    
                var enID = '1';
                var url = 'index.php';                          

                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    url:'english.php',                                  
                    data: {language_id: enID},
                    success:function(data){
                        alert('Success!');
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                    }

                });             
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The second parameter to the `error` routine is actually `textStatus` what happens if you `alert(textStatus)` in your `error` routine?

Comment: Have you inspected the response in your developer tools? The response probably isn't JSON.

Comment: Show us what `english.php` does

Comment: `Have you inspected the response in your developer tools`  I would add most browsers allow you to press f12 and then you can view the actual network request that takes place for the AJAX call.  Which will give you much more information etc..  In Mozilla, you push f12 go to network panel and make sure `XHR` is selected on the left.  And then obviously trigger the call and see what happens (click the call and check the stuff on the left like "response") etc...

Comment: file "english.php" is just to set some session value
<php
session_name ("test");
session_start();
$_SESSION["language"] = 'en';
$_SESSION["language_id"]= '1';
?>

Answer (score 0):

you may not be returning a reply from english.php

```
$result = array(
  'msg' => true
);
echo json_encode($result);
```

also use complete in javascript code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){                       
        $('#menu_en').on('click',function(){                    
            var enID = '1';
            var url = 'index.php';                          

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                url:'english.php',                                  
                data: {language_id: enID},
                success:function(data){
                    alert('Success!');
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                },
                complete: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }

            });             
        });
    });
</script>
```

complete all kinds of results..